# Prevent anchors from pushing pages to the bottom (HTML)

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a div with style="overflow: auto" with some text in it. That text has some anchors, which I have links left of the div (not within the div) and everytime I click to go to an anchor, th page goes to the bottom, like the anchor was in the bottom of the page.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```
<a href='#id2'>Link</a>
<div style='width: 100px; overflow: auto;'>
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id10' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id5' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id6' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id27' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id24' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id20' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id21' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id23' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id22' /> here
Text Inside, Big text with <hr id='#id2' /> here
<div>
```

EDIT: I'm nor using Javascript neither Iframes

EDIT: Tested in Firefox 3

Comment: What do you mean by "link in another part of the page"? Is it an iframe, a named anchor, or what?  Are you loading it via javascript?

Comment: And in which browsers do you have this problem?

Comment: It would help if you posted the HTML for the link, and the HTML for the target anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the browsers native functionality. If you want to disrupt it without using javascript, then you might as well charge hell with a water pistol because you're not going to be very successful.

Using a simple framework like jQuery would likely clear this up in just a couple lines of code. You could scroll elements into view, and prevent default activity or anchors.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like all that is happening is that the browser it trying to take your anchor to the top of the page, which is it's normal behavior in this situation. So it's not scrolling to the bottom so much as trying to get your link to the top of the page but hitting the bottom of the scroll bar before it gets there.

Some example code would be helpful though.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Is there anyway to avoid this behavior? Or another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `id` per page (id2, id3, id4, etc.) You've got id2 listed 10 times which is most likely causing your link to break. Also, you cannot start `id`s with a pound sign; valid IDs start with ([A-Za-z]).

Comment: It was just to show some code, I used different ids in the original code. Edited my post

Comment: Regardless, your IDs are still invalid since they start with a # character. You can assign a name attribute starting with a #, however. I'd suggest validating your code in case that's the issue.